# Facebook share for member-area pages

Tags: facebook-graph-api, share

I have some area on the site that is visible only when user is logged in (with specific role, it is Drupal 7 website).
I have facebook Share buttons on pages there.

When you try to share content on such pages, it works. but:

- Facebook does not get preview images and text specified. (it gets it  from wrong place - login page)
- Facebook does not count well the page shares

That is because Facebook sees the page that is to be shared as Anonymous user, i reckon.

Is there a way i could let Facebook get the picture previews, text for those pages ?
As if I am giving Facebook exclusive right to see that content as a logged in user with role ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see is finding/creating module for Drupal that allow you to assign a role to selected IP addresses and do "autologin" for them or simply to allow them to pass login without using roles. And then you can try using addresses that are posted [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/#facebook_scraper) as IPs of Facebook crawlers.

I didn't test it, so it's just an idea to try. And, of course, be sure to think if security of this solution is fair enough for you. If implementing this will do it's job well you can consider creating role that will be able to do "less" than authenticated user, to view only part that is needed to share.